# Aligning Text and Icon in the center of box in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to align the text and icons, which are in a box, to the center of it. I want it centered like this:

[image]

I tried the following: 
adding  align-content: center and justify-content: center as an inline style in the div tag for row, but no luck.  Any helps or leads are appreciated.  I have provided a jsfiddle link to show you what I have now. As of now, all the content is left.

https://jsfiddle.net/silosc/76ktyveu/4/

```
<div class="row" style="width:100%">
    <div class="report-card-i report-card-i-height">
        <h3 class="m-l-35 p-t-25 p-b-10">Stats</h3>
        <div class="fa-orange m-t-10 m-b-15">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                    <i class="fa fa-star m-r-15">Stat1</i>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                    <i class="fa fa-star m-r-15">Stat2</i>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                    <i class="fa fa-star m-r-15">Stat3</i>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
   .report-card-i{
    background: orange;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

 .report-card-i-height {
    min-height: 280px;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
        }

.report-name {
    font-family: Questrial;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #f0522f !important;
        }
</style>
```

Comment: Try with `text-align: center;`

Comment: I would suggest you use a flex layout to achieve what you want. [Here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is a good place to start with. (ps: justify-content and align-items/align-content are used with a flex layout display, otherwise they are useless)

Comment: The CSS in your question doesn't even closely resemble the image you provided.

Comment: use line-height property on icons

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using bootstrap you can use the `text-left` class. Also a lot of your bootstrap margins and padding classes are set wrong... margins are `mr-1` to `mr-5`. Same format for paddings

```css
.report-card-i {
  background: orange;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.report-card-i-height {
  min-height: 280px;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.report-name {
  font-family: Questrial;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #f0522f !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row" style="width:100%">
  <div class="report-card-i report-card-i-height">
    <h3 class="ml-5 pt-5 pb-2">Stats</h3>
    <div class="fa-orange mt-5 mb-5">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3 text-center">
          <i class="fa fa-star">Stat1</i>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
          <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3 text-center">
          <i class="fa fa-star m-r-15">Stat2</i>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
          <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3 text-center">
          <i class="fa fa-star m-r-15">Stat3</i>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
          <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: .fa { margin-left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%); },
and if you want space between the icon and the text then try: .fa-star:before { padding-right: 20px; }